# R: possible to use function with two arguments for Map?

Tags: r, functional-programming

What's the right approach to using Map for a function with two arguments in R?

I could get the same effect by using a function which takes 1 argument that consists of a list, and then pass in a list of lists, but I'd like to know if there's a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just feed in the extra arguments as a vector like `mapply`.

```
Map('+', 1:5, 2:6)
```

You can name them if you want. If they're not long enough they're recycled out to the right length (e.g. `n` here)

```
Map(rnorm, n=1, mean=1:5, sd=1:5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `mapply(f, c(a,b,c,...))` = `c(f(a), f(b), f(c), ...)`, it is unclear what those extra arguments should be. If the additional arguments are fixed (or are derived from the element itself), you can use an anonymous function: `mapply(function(x) g(1, true, x, 42), c(a,b,c,...))`.